# randomForest() for R Version 4.0.3

Tags: r, installation, random-forest, install.packages

I have tried to install randomForest() directly from the archived links with zero success. Every time I get the same error:

Warning in install.packages :
package ‘https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/randomForest/randomForest_4.6-14.tar.gz’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Any help would be appreciated, thanks! I have looked at other posts on the site, but none of the things have worked and they are geared towards version 4.0.2 (I don't know how big of a difference that makes)

Comment: What do you mean "directly from the archived links"?  What happens if you `remotes::install_version("randomForest", version = "4.6-14")` ?

Comment: I receive this error.  ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘randomForest’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/randomForest’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/gz/t3pv6ckx1dl7qtxx0hpt1ph80000gp/T//Rtmp1WDbgd/remotes241f3d34ebdc/randomForest’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: that's not quite enough information to know what's going on. This package contains Fortran and C code, so see https://mac.r-project.org/tools/ for info on how to install it (or install the `checkpoint` package and figure out how to use it)